# Laravel AngularJs automate urls

Tags: angularjs, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

How could I make this work in `gulp / elixer` :

Right now In my angularJs project I put everything manually in my index.html like this:

```
<script src="angular/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
<script src="angular/controllers/schoolController.js"></script>
```

How could I automate this with `gulp / elixer`?

Already tried things like this:

```
mix.scripts([
    'app.js',
    'controllers/**/*.js',
    'services/**/*.js',
    'directives/**/*.js'
]);
```

But that's obviously not working

Thankyou

Comment: Webpack and Browserify are both supported by Elixir.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes but how should I do that?

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/ http://browserify.org/articles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mix.scripts([
    'app.js',
    'controllers',
    'services',
    'directives'
]);
```

I discovered that if you don't have an extension, elixir will check for scripts in the folder by default.

Comment: thanks for your tip. But I receive Cannot find module '/Users/jamie/Code/forum/resources/assets/js/controllers/**/*'

Comment: Make sure to specify the path where those folders are.